# How to use onchange in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a `<td>` which is editable. I want to send the edited new data to function and how can I get the data in the `<td>` tag, can anyone help me.

```
<td   (blur) ='showsavephonemodel(i want the newly edited value here i.e student.phone)'  contenteditable="true"  class ='phone' >
       {{student.phone}}    
 </td>
```

Comment: Trying to bind `(change)` event to `td` and not an `input` field is the first thing that stands out to me.

Comment: I have an editable table..

Comment: Not according to that code. What library are you using to make your table editable? Can you show a bit more of your Component and Template?

Comment: No library ,i just put contenteditable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `(keyup)` or `(blur)` event instead,

```
<td (keyup)='showsavephonemodel()' class ='phone'>
     {{student.phone}}  
</td>


<td (blur)='showsavephonemodel()' class ='phone'>
     {{student.phone}}  
</td>
```

Comment: With this the moment i change a single number  i am getting popup as save changes?But i want the popup only after entering the full number,which is like onchange?

Comment: I edited my code,here i had <td> element which is editable,i want to send the edited value to the function.I use #value for input tag but how to get the local value in <td> tag.?

Comment: Your question is not clear. When you edit td, does it appear as an input control? Does input control have #local variable? Could you please ask it asa separate question if you think it requires more concentration?

Comment: I can't see any #localvariable in your edited question. That's why I said please come up with a new question. But as you reached to your limit, I'm afraid how to go ahead. You question is still not clear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127082/discussion-between-micronyks-and-nlr-p).